# Typo3 tx-news - Error after install bootstrap

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

i get tx-news not to run. Since two days i tried everything without winning.

1. installed a fresh typo3 7.6.11
2. installed tx-news
3. Included news to base template
4. Added content element news list to one page
5. Write a news
6. Go to page and all is fine, the list with one news appear.
7. install theme_bootstrap and choose for this site
8. From here on i get only "Oops, an error occurred!"

What did i wrong ?
May i have to override the constants ?
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/TwitterBootstrap/Index.html
Have i to modify these entries ? What to enter there?
How do tx-news knows, what to use? normal or bootstrap ?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You have no error details because of some default TypoScript configuration. Please add the following line to your global TypoScript configuration, you should then see a proper error message explaining what is wrong.

`config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0`

When you get there, if you are still unable to resolve your issue, let us know. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Additionally i have to enable the debug mode in the install tool in configuration presets.
Now i see a detailed log trace. Wonderful !

First part:

> #1289386765: Could not analyse class: "Tx_News_ViewHelpers_ExcludeDisplayedNewsViewHelper" maybe not loaded
>   or no autoloader? Class
>   Tx_News_ViewHelpers_ExcludeDisplayedNewsViewHelper does not exist 
>   TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Exception\UnknownObjectException
>   thrown in file
>   /homepages/31/d356311073/htdocs/typo3_src-7.6.11/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Object/Container/ClassInfoFactory.php
>   in line 37.

Maybe i make a mistake by adding theme_bootstrap.
1. I get extension theme_bootstrap (many other dependencies were also installed)
2. I remove bootstrap_package from include static (if not i have two footers but same error)
3. i add Themes
4. i add Content Elements

If i don't add Content Elements no Content Elements were shown on page. Only header incl. menu and footer.

Thanks for help !!!